# Scala: match and parse an integer string?

Tags: scala, parsing, match

I'm looking for a way to matching a string that may contain an integer value. If so, parse it. I'd like to write code similar to the following:

```
  def getValue(s: String): Int = s match {
       case "inf" => Integer.MAX_VALUE 
       case Int(x) => x
       case _ => throw ...
  }
```

The goal is that if the string equals "inf", return Integer.MAX_VALUE. If the string is a parsable integer, return the integer value. Otherwise throw.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Define an extractor

```
object Int {
  def unapply(s : String) : Option[Int] = try {
    Some(s.toInt)
  } catch {
    case _ : java.lang.NumberFormatException => None
  }
}
```

Your example method

```
def getValue(s: String): Int = s match {
  case "inf" => Integer.MAX_VALUE 
  case Int(x) => x
  case _ => error("not a number")
}
```

And using it

```
scala> getValue("4")
res5: Int = 4

scala> getValue("inf")
res6: Int = 2147483647

scala> getValue("helloworld")
java.lang.RuntimeException: not a number
at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:76)
at .getValue(<console>:8)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:4)
at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$result(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Na...
```

Comment: So you can just open up an object { } like that and add methods to an existing class? Cool (I think...).

Comment: Never mind, I understand now that object Int{} is creating a new Int class in your namespace.

Comment: It actually might be more efficient to use regular expressions to match the contents of the string, rather than catching the exception.

Comment: @DanielSpiewak, is that due to exceptions breaking Referential Transparency?

Answer (score 11):

This is better IMHO:

```
val IntRegEx = "(\\d+)".r
def getValue(s: String): Option[Int] =
  s match {
    case "inf"         => Some(Int.MaxValue)
    case IntRegEx(num) => Some(num.toInt)
    case _             => None
  }

getValue("inf")          // Some(2147483647)
getValue("123412")       // Some(123412)
getValue("not-a-number") // None
```

Of course, it doesn't throw any exceptions, but if you really want it, you may use:

```
getValue(someStr).getOrElse(error("NaN"))
```

Comment: If you pass "20100200300" as the value, you're going to get an exception. It'll pass your regex but that's (no moon) too big to be an Int and throw an exception.

Comment: @NateH06 You're right, and the chosen answer does not have that flaw it seems. There should be a `case` catching those too-big number, or maybe we could use `scala.math.BigInt` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a guard:

```
def getValue(s: String): Int = s match {
  case "inf" => Integer.MAX_VALUE 
  case _ if s.matches("[+-]?\\d+")  => Integer.parseInt(s)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
def readIntOpt(x: String) =
  if (x == "inf")
    Some(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  else
    scala.util.Try(x.toInt).toOption
```

Answer (score 1):

an improved version of James Iry's extractor:

```
object Int { 
  def unapply(s: String) = scala.util.Try(s.toInt).toOption 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]):

```
"5".toIntOption   // Option[Int] = Some(5)
"abc".toIntOption // Option[Int] = None
```

we can cast the `String` as an `Option[Int]` after checking if it's equal to "inf":

```
if (str == "inf") Some(Int.MaxValue) else str.toIntOption
// "inf"   =>   Option[Int] = Some(2147483647)
// "347"   =>   Option[Int] = Some(347)
// "ac4"   =>   Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getValue(s: String): Int = s match {
    case "inf" => Integer.MAX_VALUE 
    case _ => s.toInt
}


println(getValue("3"))
println(getValue("inf"))
try {
    println(getValue("x"))
}
catch {
    case e => println("got exception", e)
    // throws a java.lang.NumberFormatException which seems appropriate
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good way to meet my immediate needs, however it's not the generic solution i was looking for. For instance, perhaps I would want to execute a block depending on what type the string was parsable to:

     def doSomething(s: String): Int = s match {
       case Int(x) => println("you got an int")
       case Float(x) => println("you got a float")
       case _ => throw ...
  }